# Get error message text of solr

Tags: curl, solr, libcurl

I have configures solr and executing search using CURL. On failures curl returns response code 400 which is kind of generic.

Is there any way I can fetch error message text which solr has thrown on console or log file?

Answer (score 0):

Bet way, is to go to your solr via http.
I suggest you run the queries [in Debug here (replace CORE by your core name in URI)](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/CORE/query) and after to run curl

You can run the admin console : [admin console](http://localhost:8983/solr)
you can see all the logs here [logging uri](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging)
and also you can [configure the error level (show/hide logs)](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging/level)